# Attachment Last Modified Date on Object

Tags: custom-object, attachment

I have created a custom object with a Master-Detail relationship to the Account object in SFDC.  The purpose of this custom object, for the moment, is to act as a "shell" to house account plan PowerPoint documents that our Sales team create.  I am creating a custom object instead of using the notes & Attachments on the Account object, because we have other documents in that related list that will confuse the search.

What I need to do is get the last modified date of the attached plan datestamped to the custom object record so we can report on when the Account Plans were last updated.  Does anyone know how I can do this, with Apex being a last resort as I would need to go through another group to get that approved?

Comment: Are you using Attachments or Content records?

Comment: I am using the standard Notes & Attachments related list on the custom object, but I am open to anything else that might work.